# GnuCash : How to find net amount of two accounts in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash

I have a party, ABC, who is a vendor for one product and a customer for another.

I created two accounts; one as Payable and one as Receivable.

How can I check if I have to see the net amount of these two accounts?

I tried **Balance Sheet** by filtering only these two accounts, but it is not showing the difference. At present, I am calculating manually.

If there is a facility it will be useful to know the net balance of a  party which is both receivable and payable.

**Note**: You can derive the net balance using **Transaction Report** but it would be a lengthy report.